# static variable get parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sharepoint

I have this code on my asp net page (it´s an url with an id www.example.com/GestHC.aspx?pID=36006394 )

```
public partial class GestHC : WebPart
{
    public GestHC ()
    {
    }
    static int iIDHC;

    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        InitializeControl();
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            iIDHC = -1;
            string str = this.Page.Request["pID"];  
            iIDHC = int.Parse(str.Replace("'", ""));

            MyModel hc = MyModel.readdata(iIDHC);

            this.txtName.text = hc.name
            this.txtSurname.text = hc.surname 
            ...

        }
    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MyModel hc = new MyModel();
            if (iIDHC != -1)
            {
                hc = MyModel.readdata(iIDHC);                
            }
            else
            {
                hc.name = txtname.text;
                hc.surname = txtSurname.text;

            }

            hc.dir1 = dir.text;
            ...

            hc.savedata()
        }
         catch (Exception)
         {
             this.navegarAGridMensaje("Error");
         }
    }    
}
```

The problem is that when user loads the data and saves it, everything works fine but when more than 2 user or browsers works together the data is mixed. For example:

```
User a creates:
 ID = 10
 Name = XXX
 Age = 8

User b creates:
 ID = 11
 Name = YYY
 Age = 10
```

Then if user a updates his data (ID=10), maybe setting the `Age` to `80` the result is

```
User a creates:
 ID = 10
 Name = XXX
 Age = 8

User b creates:
 ID = 11
 Name = YYY
 Age = 88
```

So the (ID=11) is updated. Debuggin.. I could see that with an static id, when the second user loads it can read the previous user iIDHC....

How to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Session object instead (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

When you are store your data in static variable - it will be shared between all users in your app.

Comment: we can not use session variables. I´ll go with hidden inputs maybe

Comment: Up to you. You can use cookies too if it is suitable to your business need.

Answer (score 0):

Make it non static!

```
public partial class GestHC : WebPart
{
    public GestHC ()
    {
    }
    private int iIDHC = -1;//initialize here
...
}
```

also you dont have to initialize in page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //iIDHC = -1; -  not required as you can initialize it during declaration
}
```

Comment: yap, but if I opened de ID=10 when I click the save button, iIDHC value is -1 instead of 10. I´m thinking maybe to save the iIDHC value in a hidden inputbox or something...

Comment: Hmm.. How about updating iIDHC to 10 when you are saving iIDHC. I am bit confused, so cant exactly point my finger at the problem. But the idea is to keep the ID in one place and keep it updated everytime it changes for a user.  An instance variable should be good enough to handle this.